# safest & fastest way to set Series value to 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series:

```
    s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I want to replace s values to be all 0 (creating a new Series is fine but I want to do it most efficiently), e.g. `pd.Series(0, index=s.index)`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `pd.Series(0, index=s.index)` is probably the best way to create the series. If it's all non-NaN (since NaN * 0 is NaN) numbers you could do `s * 0`, but this overly specific/less clear as to what's happening.

Comment: thank you @HenryEcker. Is it possible to reset the values of the series without creating another one? something like `s.values = 0` (although this doesn't work)

Comment: `s[:] = 0` would work.